# Vista media player behavior on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Is there a way to get the (or a) media player on Windows 7 to behave like it did on Vista? In particular, given a folder of files, if you select one halfway down and then click Play All, the new media player will ignore the selection and start at the beginning of the folder, where the desired behavior is as in Vista, to start playing at the selected item. Is there a way to get that back?

Comment: I assume you mean Windows Media Player. What version are you using? 11? 12? "Classic"?

Comment: 12, the one that came with Windows 7.